Compatibility of Jar compiled with newer JDK
I have a maven project using Java 17. The maven-compiler-pugin is set to <release>17</release>.
If I build this project with a newer JDK version (for example 21), will the produced Jar still be runnable with a JRE 17?

Yes it should be. You should generally try to set the version as low as possible

Unless you use some newer feature not present in 17. Also there is a caveat about Unicode, As a limitation of the --release implementation, the Unicode version of the given target platform is not used during compilation; the Unicode version of the current platform is used instead. See also JEP 247.

Even if you use newer feature the build will fail in such case!

Short answer - yes.
The release property you're using should cover both the produced class version and the usage of API that is available on Java 17.
There's always a caveat that you may be implicitly relying on some undocumented internal behavior and/or bug fix present in Java 21 that won't be present in Java 17, but those should really be rare cases.
